# Swiper.js not scrolling to final element

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swiper.js

I tried to add swiper.js to tab elements in Oxygen Builder but it is not scrolling to the end unless I set swiper.js to 'centeredslides:true' or 'loop:true' but loop breaks Oxygen Builder tabs.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Can provide video of error if needed..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        // Optional parameters
        freeMode: true,
      slidesPerView: 8,
      centeredSlides: true,
                spaceBetween: 0,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        freeMode: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        scrollbar: {
            el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
            hide: false,
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting same problem and I think nobody seems to know any solution about this I couldnt find any solution